# Robots.txt restriction of category URLs

Tags: url, robots.txt

I was unable to find information about my case. I want to restrict the following types of URLs to be indexed:

website.com/video-title/video-title/

(my website produces such double URL copies of my video-articles)

Each video article starts with the word "video" in the beginning of its URL.

So what I want to do is to restrict all URLs that have website.com/"any-url"/video-any-url"

This way I will remove all the doubled copies. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the original robots.txt specification.

But some parsers may support wildcards in `Disallow` anyway, for example, [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en):

> Googlebot (but not all search engines) respects some pattern matching.

So for Google’s bots, you could use the following line:

```
Disallow: /*/video
```

This should block any URLs whose paths starts with anything, and contains "video", for example:

- `/foo/video`
- `/foo/videos`
- `/foo/video.html`
- `/foo/video/bar`
- `/foo/bar/videos`
- `/foo/bar/foo/bar/videos`

Other parsers not supporting this would interpret it literally, i.e., they would block the following URLs:

- `/*/video`
- `/*/videos`
- `/*/video/foo`